# Is there a way to automatically assign thumbnails to all files in Wordpress Download Manager using ImageMagick?

Tags: wordpress, imagemagick

I'm using WPDM Pro, and I have already 1200 files, all images (PSD, PDF, EPS, JPG). Is there a way to automatically assign thumbnails to all files in Wordpress Download Manager using ImageMagick?

Comment: Welcome to SO. In general, it's best to include the code for something you have tried.

Comment: Please elaborate a little. Too little info. Also list what you have tried, and what problems you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9281575/wordpress-featured-image-all-post-slugs-matching-image-file-name/30838656#30838656) I just fix some details and it works like a charm!

```
<?php
// Get All Posts.
$allPosts = get_posts(array('numberposts' => -1, 'post_type' => 'wpdmpro'));
// Specify where the images are located.
$themePATH = get_theme_root().'/'.get_stylesheet().'/thumbs/';
// The uploads directory for your blog.
$uploads= wp_upload_dir();
// List of images including extensions.
$images = listImages($themePATH,true);
// List of images without extensions.
$imageNames = listImages($themePATH,false);

function reverseSlug($string){
    $string = str_replace("-", " ", $string);// Convert hyphen to space
    $string = ucwords($string);// Capitalize the beginning of each word
    return $string;
}

// Retrieve all images from the specified directory.
// Output array with and without file extensions.
function listImages($dirname=".",$display) {
    $ext = array("jpg", "png", "jpeg", "gif");
    $files = array();
    if($handle = opendir($dirname)){
        while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){
            for($i=0;$i<sizeof($ext);$i++){
                if(strstr($file, ".".$ext[$i])){
                    $files[] = $file;
                }
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }
    sort($files);
    foreach($files as $theFile){
        $info = pathinfo($theFile);
        $fileName = basename($theFile,'.'.$info['extension']);
        $files1[] = $fileName;
    }
    if($display == false){
        return ($files1);
    }
    if($display == true){
        return($files);
    }
}


for($i = 0; $i < count($allPosts); $i++){
    // Check if post slugs match image slugs.
    if (is_array($imageNames)) {
        $check[$i] = in_array($allPosts[$i]->post_name, $imageNames);
    } else {
        echo 'error';
    };


    if($check[$i] == 1){
        echo 'Yes, post title matches image name.<br />'.PHP_EOL;
        // Search through the image slugs for a direct match with the post slug.
        $search[$i] = array_search($allPosts[$i]->post_name, $imageNames);
        $filename = $images[$search[$i]];
        $newfile = $uploads['path'].'/'.$filename;
        // Copy the image from theme folder to uploads directory.
        copy($themePATH.$filename, $newfile);
        // Delete image from theme folder.
        unlink($themePATH.$filename);
        // Retrieve the file type from the file name.
        $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype(basename($filename), null);
        // Construct the attachment array.
        $attachment = array(
            'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
            'guid' => $uploads['url'].'/'.$filename,
            'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', reverseSlug(basename($filename))),
            'post_content' => '',
            'post_status' => 'inherit'
        );
        // This function inserts an attachment into the media library.
        $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $newfile, $allPosts[$i]->ID);
        // You must first include the image.php file
        // For the function wp_generate_attachment_metadata() to work.
        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
        // This function generates metadata for an image attachment.
        // It also creates a thumbnail and other intermediate sizes
        // of the image attachment based on the sizes defined on
        // the Settings_Media_Screen.
        $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $newfile);
        if(!is_wp_error($attach_id)){
            // Update metadata for an attachment.
            wp_update_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $attach_data);
            // Updates the value of an existing meta key (custom field) for the specified post.
            update_post_meta($allPosts[$i]->ID, '_thumbnail_id', $attach_id);
        }
    }
    else{
        echo 'No matches found.<br />'.PHP_EOL;
    }
}
?>
```